# SPARQL query on Protege 4.3

Tags: sparql, protege4

The following query (preceded by relevant prefixes of course)

posed on an ontology (`.owl` file) gives the `object` properties or `data` properties?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?predicate
    WHERE { ?subject ?predicate ?object }
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wholly depends on what the data in the triple store or file contains. Variable `?predicate` will match the predicate of the triple, and that predicate might be a datatype property or an object property in OWL, or neither of those if you're not querying an OWL ontology. Likewise, `?object` will match an RDF resource or a literal, again depending on what the data says.